# Increase in moving average by an absolute value

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I have the code for a condition which is true when there is an increase in the SMA9 by a percentage (3%) which is shown below. How would I alter this so that instead of a percentage it is by an absolute value, e.g. an increase by $10 ?

```
SMA9 = ta.sma(close, 9)

// Calculating Percentage Change
buySMA = (close/SMA9)

condition = buySMA >= 0.03
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this

```
SMA9 = ta.sma(close, 9)
condition = close >= SMA9 + 10
```

Comment: Thank you very much. For an absolute value decrease, would the code then be: 'condition = close <= SMA9 - 10'?

Comment: Correct. You got it.